# Can embeddable class have constructors?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a class with embeddable annotation and, when I try to pass an instance to an entity, I get an exception:

> org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for
> entity:  : entity.D3

```
enum Figure {
    SQUARE, TRIANGLE
};

@Embeddable
public class D3 {
    float z;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    Figure figure;

    public D3(float z, Figure f) {
        this.z = z;
        this.figure = f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hibernate is creating an object using the default constructor "public D3(){}" which is not existing (since you created an own constructor, the default constructor is not available unless you create it as well). Additional initialization has to be done using additional methods. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looking for a default constructor (i.e. parameterless), in addition to any you have defined:

```
@Embeddable
public class D3 {
    float z;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    Figure figure;

    public D3() { //I've added this
    }

    public D3(float z, Figure f) {
        this.z = z;
        this.figure = f;
    }
}
```